# bootstamp/ Change color of navBar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the color of my navaigation bar in boostamp (The color is now black).

I use the next code:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In the body section:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
```

What I need to add in order to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this  `navbar-inverse`  to `navbar-success` or `navbar-info` or `navbar-warning` or `navbar-danger`.

You can refer bootstrap for the  colors for these classes.

[**See here**](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `body .navbar-inner { background: #ffffff }` in your CSS, where #ffffff is the colour you're after.

Answer (score 0):

update property in navbar-inner class.

```
  background : youWant; // color
```